# Finding scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having an issue with my Gmail account automatically archiving emails. I tried to create a script to do this to certain emails, but it is doing it to all of them.

Does anyone know where I can go to view all of my active scripts and see if something is running on accident?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Account settings > Security > Manage access

or search through your messages in Gmail to find the authorization notifications.